# not able to show Google Map for Specific Coordinates

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I am Trying to Show Map for A Country 'Haiti'

Found its coordinates as 18.5333° N, 72.3333° W

I try to put it in following Code in Different ways But it is not working

Maps works fine for my own location

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/263/

My Code  :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {

       //Tried to put static lati longi in many ways
      p.coords.latitude = '18.5333';
        p.coords.longitude = '72.3333';

   //also Tried this :
   //var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5333, 72.3333);
   //var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('18.5333', '72.3333');


        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, 
   p.coords.longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: LatLng,
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"),     
 mapOptions);
          });
} else {
    alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}
```

What is missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

ok Found the Solution ..

Just needed to to change the coordinates

Following Site provides the Correct coordinates as location :

http://www.hamstermap.com/geocoder.html

My Code :

```
var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.971187,-72.275215),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/263/